# Запись html в файл

Tags: python, bs4

У меня есть парсер он щелкает по вкладкам на странице поиска, нужно сделать чтоб заходя на вкладку он копировал html код из body сайты не известны,что в поиске нашел по запросу вот с первой и захожу.
Нашел много всего с помощью requests и BS, но везде там под конкретную ссылку типо:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
r = requests.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47503845)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
print(soup)
with open ('/tmp/test.html', 'a') as f:
    f.write(str(soup))
```

Comment: `with open('/tmp/test.html', 'wb') as f: f.write(r.content)`?

Comment: for i in range(len(links)):
    links[i].click()
    i+=1
    driver.back()
нужно после клика сохранить содержимое

Comment: BeautifulSoup кликами не занимаеться это к Selenium обратись

Comment: Так у меня selenium и кликает, вопрос как сохранить html с кликнутого сайта.